# How can I use slotted deployments in Azure DevOps for an Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I'm having some problems with slotted deployments in Azure DevOps. The problem is that my app goes down during deployment. But once the deployment finishes, it comes up again.

My app comes with an *azuredeploy.json* file: https://pastebin.com/CPVzE5hM.

While trying to access my web app once it is deploying, it seems to go down at the first step:

```
Azure Deployment: Create Or Update Resource Group acti...
```

There are usually no changes to the *azuredeploy.json* file, so I don't understand why it goes down at this step. There is nothing to create -- it exists before, and there is nothing to update either.

I have set up the slots manually in Azure Portal. The deployment mode is *incremental*.

[image]

Comment: If you already create the slot via Azure portal, and you are not doing anything to the template file. May I know the reason why you add your first task? What do you want to achieve with it?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use slotted deployments in Azure DevOps for an Azure App Service?

According to your description, we need to create new deployment slot for an existing WebApp.

So, we need to check if we create or update for the new deployment slot instead of the Production:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "siteName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "slotName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-04-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/Sites/Slots",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('siteName'), '/', parameters('slotName'))]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {},
            "resources": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The [template](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/b566c5bcf2ad3c3783b70d0082a4fc83809181f4/ARMTemplates/TodoApp.json#L175) on GitHub.

You could check the document [this](https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/10/13/deploy-azure-web-app-with-slots-using-azure-arm/), [this](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2019/10/02/Swap-slots-with-arm-templates.html) and the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707724/create-deployment-slot-for-webapp-in-azure-devops-pipeline) for some more details. If this not resolve this issue, please share your json file to use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As per some other guides, I have already created the slot in Azure Portal, so the slot exists. Just to confirm: I definitely need the slot in my template? I'm deploying incrementally. Everything works, it seems to swap the slots, but the app goes down when creating or updating the RG.

Comment: @HelloWorld, If you already created the slot manually, you do not need to add the slot in the template. If you update the RG by template, which cause the app goes down, you need to check what have you done with that ARM template, if the update related to the app service, then it cause the app goes down. Or you could share the ARM template in your question, remember replace your personal information.

Comment: I updated the question with a link to my template. The problem is that I am not doing anything to the template file, but it goes down anyway.