# Azure DevOps: Swap back production and staging

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a YAML-script that deploys my WebApp to a staging slot, then it checks if the staging slot is running. If so it uses this code to swap the staging slot to production:

```yaml
            - task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
              displayName: "Swap to production slot"
              condition: succeeded()
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.SubscriptionName }}'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: '$(AppServiceName)'
                ResourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroupName)
                SourceSlot: staging
                SwapWithProduction: true
```

After swapping I check the production and if this fails I want to swap back to the version that is now in the staging slot, but I'm not sure what is the best task for that.
Should I copy the above task and change `SourceSlot: staging` to `SourceSlot: production`?
And set `SwapWithProduction: false` and `condition: succeeded()` to `condition: failed()`?

This would be my workflow:

1. Production runs v1
2. Deploy v2 to staging slot
3. Test staging slot (v2)
4. Swap staging (v2) to production (v1)
5. Test production (v2)
6. When step 5 fails: swap staging (v1) back to production (v2)

When this is the correct approach how do I prevent the second swap (step 6) to execute when my first check (step 3) fails?

Comment: Have u seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707724/create-deployment-slot-for-webapp-in-azure-devops-pipeline ?